# Solving a system of equations with matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I have

\begin{align}
x_1 + 2x_2 & = 3 \\[0.5ex]
4x_1 + 5x_2 & = 6 \\[0.5ex]
9x_1 + 12x_2 & = 14
\end{align}

I get the reduced row echelon form of

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc|c}
      1 & 0 & 0         \\[0.55ex]
      0 & 1 & 0         \\[0.55ex]
      0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right]$$

This is obviously inconsistent but the book is saying that it isn't and gives nothing further, is this right or wrong?

Comment: I think your matrix looks kind of strange. You would want a $3 \times 2$ matrix (or a $3 \times 3$ if you want to work with the augmented matrix$).

Comment: Unless you have miscopied the system, you are right, it is inconsistent.

Comment: Maybe it is because I got to a point before the RRE form that was inconsistent so I stopped and said it is inconsistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are absolutely correct: the system *is indeed* inconsistent. As you know, there is no possible way that $0x_1 + 0x_2 = 1$, hence the inconsistency.

Since there are three equations and two unknowns, the system is "overdetermined", and the only way the system can be consistent is if one (or more) of the rows in the $RREF$ matrix were strictly a row of zeros.

Comment: Do I have to get to the RRE form to prove this or can I just show at one point in a series of valid elementary row operation the matrix was inconsistent?

Comment: Often times we encounter an inconsistent system *before* arriving at a matrix in strictly RREF.

Comment: e.g., Taking twice the The first row plus  twice the second row gives a row $(9\;\;12\;|\;15)$ which represents an equation that is inconsistent with the third original equation.

Comment: @amWhy: Could use another TU +1

Answer (score 2):

You have three equations in two unknowns.  If you add the first to twice the second, you get $9x_1+12x_2=15$, which is inconsistent with the third.